# route with ngRoute and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes

Ive just started to learn AngularJS and im trying to use angular-route but can't get it to work.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="fantasySportsApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Content/Style/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<!--Placeholder for views-->
<div data-ng-view="">
    Hejsan
    <a href="#/login">ge</a>
</div>
<script src="Content/Scripts/jQuery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="Content/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Content/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Content/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="App/app.js"></script>
<script src="Content/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my app.js looks like this:

```
var fantasySportsApp = angular.module('fantasySportsApp',  ['ngRoute']);

fantasySportsApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/login', {
    controller: 'userController',
    templateUrl: 'App/partials/login.html'
})
    .when('/startPage', {
        controller: 'startPageController',
        templateUrl: '/App/partials/startPage.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/index" });
});
```

when i start my page ill get to this url: localhost:26283/index.html#/index but it wont show me anything. the page is empty. If i inspect the html i find this in the code: "<-- ngView:  -->" think indicates that the partial view that i try to route to is supposed to start but there is nothing under the tag.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Well, you haven't configured any route for `/index`. Only for `/login` and `/startPage`. Which controller and view should angular use if you don't specify it?

Comment: i tried this:  .otherwise({
            controller: 'indexController',
            templateUrl: '/index.html'
        });

but that ended up in an infinite loop that pushed the tag: <-- ngView: --> in the html 4-5 times per second

Comment: Your initial `otherwise` is fine. But it redirects to a route `/index` that you haven't defined. Define it like the two other routes: using `when()`.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks! Now the first page works. But when i press my <a> tag  i get to this url: http://localhost:26283/index.html#/login but it still shows me the same index.html content and not the textboxes that i have in the login.html

Comment: Open the development tools of your browser, and look at the console. There must be an error listed there.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=fantasySportsApp&p1=undefined what does this mean?

Comment: Do you have a complete stack trace? If so, paste it in your question. Also, clear your console, then go the the home page of your app, then click on the Login link, and tell us when this exception happens.

Comment: what do you mean by complete stack trace? like the stack trace in visual studio? Is there a stack trace like that in chrome? The console error is there when the page is loaded even  before i have pressed the link

Comment: Then you have an error somewhere in your JavaScript. The console should display a stack trace of the JavaScript error. If it didn't display before, then it's probably in the controller of the index route.

Comment: my controllers right now are empty. Is there anything that has to be initiated for it to work?

Comment: It depends on your code. I can't see your code, and I can't see the stack trace of the error. That doesn't help to debug.